# Paradox to Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a legacy Paradox application that has been running successfully for almost 20 years using the Borland Database Engine. Data is entered into the main program by many different order takers, who then daily put the data onto a memory stick for use by laptops in many service trucks, which also use Paradox.

I just finished rewriting the used-to-be Paradox program that runs on the laptops, using Delphi XE2 Professional and TClientDataSet (briefcase model).

Now I need to upgrade the main application to a client-server model, using a Firebird server. The question is, what is the best approach, since I don't have the Enterprise Edition. I see quite a few different 3rd party tools available, or would the tools provided in the Professional Edition be sufficient?

Comment: For MSSQL, use ADO components, they're in Pro. For firebird, just get a third-party data access library that supports firebird. There are many and they are cheap. Or buy an upgrade to Enterprise, since Embarcadero's got some good deals on upgrades to Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

The tools provided in the Professional version should be fine to work with . I am assuming , you have used BDE components like TTable , TQuery etc for accessing the Paradox database . You could use the same via ODBC connection ... Best solution will be to move away from using the BDE components to ADO / other components...

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37538 provides driver information for Firebird